# how to choose any type of file and upload it to server?

Tags: android, file, retrofit, filepath, filepicker

I'm trying to choose any type of files like `.pdf` or `.doc` and ect and then upload it to server with `retrofit` library.
I'm able to choose image and video and music from my files and send it easily to server. but in api 19 and above, I can't have direct access to other files! I tried this way :

```
    private InputStream getInputStreamForVirtualFile(Uri uri, String mimeTypeFilter)
        throws IOException {

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

    String[] openableMimeTypes = resolver.getStreamTypes(uri, mimeTypeFilter);

    if (openableMimeTypes == null || openableMimeTypes.length < 1) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    return resolver
            .openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(uri, openableMimeTypes[0], null)
            .createInputStream();
}
```

this code give me `InputStream` of the file and for sending it to server with retrofit I figured to create a copy of my file, and then use that file to send it , my code is :

```
    private File getFile(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    String[] array = uri.getPath().split("/");
    File x = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + array[array.length - 1]);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(x);
    InputStream inputStream = getInputStreamForVirtualFile(uri, "*/*");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
    return x;
}
```

I am not able to send it to server yet, but these code in android 8 gives me the right file , but it android 7, I have this error :

```
The requested MIME type is not supported.
```

my question is what is the proper way to choose any type of file and send it to server with retrofit?!

and if my way is a rational way to sending any type of file, how can I fix it to support all androids such as android 7 and fix my error!?